# I wanted to shift y axis to right side in LineChart

Tags: react-native, linechart, react-native-gifted-chat

I wanted to show yAxis on right side in my LineChart. I used yAxisSide prop, it worked perfectly fine when implemented but it didn't worked when i run app next day. here is the code.

```
 <LineChart
            noOfSections={sections}
          
            width={getWidth(77)}
            
            yAxisSide={'right'} //Here is the issue
            
            height={getHeight(20)}
            yAxisOffset={ExpectedValue()}
            yAxisThickness={0}
            yAxisLabelSuffix="kg"
            xAxisLength={getWidth(65)}
            xAxisLabelTexts={ExpectedWeeks()}
            xAxisThickness={0}
            thickness={3.3}
            color="#50C878"
            curved
            
            hideRules={true}

            customDataPoint={customDataPoint}
            initialSpacing={getWidth(5)}
            spacing={getWidth(15)}
            stepValue={5}
      
            data={DataValues()}
          
          />
```

I tried shifting y axis to right side but my logic not working.I want to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which library do you use?

Comment: react-native-gifted-charts